# How change color of specific item of listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a customlistadapter as follow:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {
    List<Integer> baseOnThis;
    public CustomListViewAdapter2(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items, ArrayList<Integer> ids) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    baseOnThis= ids;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView firstHemistich;
    TextView SecondHemistich;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);


    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.hemistich_rows, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.firstHemistich = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.SecondHemistich = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.desc);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.firstHemistich.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.SecondHemistich.setText(rowItem.getDesc());

    return convertView;
}
```

now I need base on the database value that saved on Arraylist of "baseOnThis" change the color of item of listview but I can't. Is there any idea how should  I do this?
Please let me know if my question is wrong and don't minus me

Comment: put Simple Plan answer inside your getView method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if(position == 3){
        holder.SecondHemistich.setTextColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1));
}
```

Comment: I use your answer but It colord 3rd position and some position randomly as well how should I control it?

Comment: I run your code its working properly. i think you have customize more on this page.

Comment: You are right but the other part of code just for change the font work. I just put .setTextColor(Color.RED); instate of your code and put it at top of the return

Comment: If you are still getting random row coloring it is because the position parameter is the position in the current view at the time it gets redrawn so if you are scrolling position == 3 will be a different row as you scroll. I use an underlying data object (e.g. array list) to hold my data and the position in that to define colors. That way they won't change with scrolling. My solution uses myGlobalArray.get(position).getPosition().

Comment: Thanks Gravitoid for answering, Yesterday I watch the number that position show, the numbers depend on the way of scrolling. means if you move up show first row at top and vers. But  I can't understand your means clearly and change my code acording that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better would be to read a little bit about android Adapters [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Basicaly getView method works like **for** or **foreach** and returns View objects for every item in your array or list that you can modify as you want, you just need to make any required changes inside getView() method
About changing color you can get main Layout container from your already inflated convertView and change its background color property as you want

Answer (score 0):

change your `getView`-method to this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);


    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.hemistich_rows, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.firstHemistich = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.SecondHemistich = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.desc);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.firstHemistich.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.SecondHemistich.setText(rowItem.getDesc());

    // change color of item
    if (yourValueHere) {
        holder.SecondHemistich.setTextColor(yourColor);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

change yourValueHere and yourColor... This will colorize each item based on the value yourValueHere.