# How to get a ListView's child view at specific index

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I need to dynamically change the background color of a child view of a `ListView` at a specific index. So I need to get the view first before applying the background.

I have tried the following.

`getViewAt(int index)` - this is not applicable to `ListView`.

`getChildAt(int index)` - this gives runtime NPE error

A Google search returns irrelevant results.

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You need to do that on the getView method of your custom adapter. Check if the position is the same you want to change and apply your background changes.

Comment: you can use adapter.getView() but you may want to do that on the getView() itself

Comment: `listView.getChildAt(index);` should work. Show code and exception trace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How change color of specific item of listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755522/how-change-color-of-specific-item-of-listview)

Comment: `A Google search returns irrelevant results.` I doubt you really searched, since **I did** and got **a lot** of **relevant** results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075975/redraw-a-single-row-in-a-listview

Comment: @FrankN.Stein The results that I got were about getting the index of a view.

Comment: @PedroOliveira getView() is not recommended for dynamic change of background. Like when the view is already visible.

Comment: The person who marked this question as duplicate is a wrong. It is possible to set the background of a ListView's child  through the adapter, but what if I want to change the backround after getView() has already been called and the view is already drawn?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein the answers don't tell how I can get a child view

Comment: Check my answer, y'all. My answer will help you better understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

I really think that one should not have to post code and logcat for a question that is similar to "How to set background image".

Anyway my answer is, in short, set position as tag for every child in the listview through your adapter's getView() and then get any child using findViewWithTag(Object tag).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, parent, false);        .
    convertView.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
}
```

And whenever you need to get a specific child.

```
View v = mylistview.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(index));
```

To change background color.

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.some_color);
```

Comment: This is the answer that I was expecting. And it is exactly what the title asks. So whoever marked this as duplicate, could you tell me if this answer is in the question that this one is a duplicate of?

Answer (score 1):

Use getChildAt(index) from ViewGroup to get View.