# onItemClickListener: How to make two different listeners on each view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've got an item of list view. It has textview and imageview. After clicking on imageview it has to create intent after clicking on text view it has to strike text in it. I have created intent. Created the list. But dont know how to separate listener for two views.

Thats my code
xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Layout for a single list item in the list of list -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#2B3D4D"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#AEB6BD" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

java

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /** Identifier for the pet data loader */
    private static final int LIST_LOADER = 0;

    /** Adapter for the ListView */
    ListCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Find the ListView which will be populated with the list data
        ListView listListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        listListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        // Setup an Adapter to create a list item for each row of list data in the Cursor.
        // There is no items data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
        mCursorAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, null);
        listListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        // Setup the item click listener
        listListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Create new intent to go to {@link EditorActivity}
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);

                // Form the content URI that represents the specific item that was clicked on,
                // by appending the "id" (passed as input to this method) onto the
                // {@link ListEntry#CONTENT_URI}.
                // For example, the URI would be "content://com.example.android.list/list/2"
                // if the pet with ID 2 was clicked on.
                Uri currentItemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

                // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
                intent.setData(currentItemUri);

                // Launch the {@link EditorActivity} to display the data for the current pet.
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Kick off the loader
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_LOADER, null, this);
    }
```

Comment: this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336736/8164071

Comment: Try if(position==0){} if(position==1){} inside listListview  onitemclicklistener.

Comment: @HasanSaykın can you please show me full example?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

```
// Setup the item click listener
listListView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
                             AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
                           view, int position, long id) {

       View selectedView = adapterView.getSelectedView();
        if (selectedView instanceof ImageView) {

        } else if (selectedView instanceof TextView) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What is doing getSelectedView? in parent has to be main ListView?

Answer (score 0):

In adapter getView() method you can set OnClickListeners separately for both textView and imageView.

For example like this

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff for imageview
        }
    });

textView..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff for textview
        }
    });
```

Comment: But the listview takes onItemClick precedence

Answer (score 0):

you can done this by define imageview and textview like this first give ids

```
final ImageView iv=(ImageView)emptyView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
//emptyview is your list item layout 
//similar for textview and you can now impement listner in onitemclicklistner

 listListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

//same for textview
}
});
```

i hope this is helpfull

Comment: I tried. But doesnt see ID from adapter asking it to make Static after that show error Exception dispatching input event. Screenshot http://joxi.ru/Grq9Rb7uNzDXBr

Comment: than make it final

Comment: but it gives me null exception

Comment: i got exception in onclick method